# AWS REST API signature errors

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, aws-rest-api

I want to retrieve AWS SSM parameters in my R code, but R doesn't have an AWS SDK (to my knowledge). So I decided to use the AWS REST API, which is simple to use *except* for needing bespoke signatures calculated for all requests. Happily the [package aws.signature](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/aws.signature/index.html) generates these - but I couldn't find examples for how to use it.

My code successfully generated a signature with the package, but then gave me this:

```
InvalidSignatureException
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
```

Most of the examples online for the REST API refer to [AWS S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RESTAuthentication.html), which also didn't help with debugging as those have a slightly different structure!

So my question is: how to debug this error?

Answer (score 2):

First things first: a working example!

```R
body <- '{"Names": ["/my/ssm/path"]}'
region <- Sys.getenv("AWS_REGION", unset = "eu-west-1")

headers <- list(
    "Host" = paste0("ssm.", region, ".amazonaws.com"),
    "Date" = format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ", tz = "UTC"),
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
    "Content-Length" = as.character(nchar(body)),
    "X-Amz-Target" = "AmazonSSM.GetParameters"
)

# Use the headers to sign the request for AWS' validation.
headers$Authorization <- aws.signature::signature_v4_auth(
    canonical_headers = headers,
    datetime = headers$Date,
    request_body = body,
    region = region,
    verb = "POST",
    action = "/",
    service = "ssm"
)$SignatureHeader

# If we're using temporary credentials, we must provide an extra header.
security.token <- Sys.getenv('AWS_SESSION_TOKEN', unset = "")
if (security.token != "") {
    headers[["X-Amz-Security-Token"]] <- security.token
}

# Send the request.
handle <- curl::new_handle()
curl::handle_setopt(handle, post = TRUE, postfields = charToRaw(body))
do.call(curl::handle_setheaders, c(handle, headers))
```

And: a few tips.

- The `aws.signature` function returns an object with all the intermediate steps like `StringToSign`. I ended up `print()`ing this and comparing it with a related [AWS example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RESTAuthentication.html).
- Signatures are very case sensitive! For example, `verb = "post"` rather than `POST` will cause an invalid signature error.
- `action` seems to be mostly used for AWS S3: other services seem to use `/`